# SharePoint List View open in Quick Edit mode as Default

Tags: task-list, edit-mode-panel

Does anyone know, why my Task List View opens in Quick Edit by default? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have created a view with datasheet which tends to open in the edit mode. You can set it to default Standard view. Refer this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9) to change the default view of the list

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Someone probably created a custom View and set it as the default. Browse through the existing Views and find the original View. Edit that View and make it the default.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.
I looked at the view in SharePoint designer, the view Type property was set to "GRID."

Comparing it to a normal view, I changed the type property to "HTML" and it loaded how I wanted afterwards.