# SP Online Document Library Defaults to Grid View

Tags: sharepoint-online

Recently one of our online sites started displaying Document Libraries in Grid View by default. Users can click on "Exit Grid View" and go about their business but it is causing some confusion for some of them.

We don't recall making any changes to cause this.

Any insight on why this happened is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this situation only occur in one library or all the libraries? Through my test, if you create a datasheet view and set it as the default, the above situation may occur. You can find the original view and set it as the default.

Reference:
[SharePoint List View open in Quick Edit mode as Default](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239072/sharepoint-list-view-open-in-quick-edit-mode-as-default)

Comment: Thank you. There were no additional views but this made me think of creating a new view, set it as default and everything went back to normal.